# Determine type of widget on Gtk.drag_motion

Tags: gtk, gtk3, vala

In my app I have two widgets which I can drag and drop to each other. When the widget is dragged above another widget there is a motion revealer, which indicates that a widget is dragged over another one. This works fine.

Now I want to style the motion revealer differently, depending on which widget is currently dragged.

Is there a way to get the type information of the dragged widget during the `drag_motion` callback?

Comment: Are you using `gtk4` or `Gtk+-3`?

Comment: Sorry didn't see the tag in the question. You can also try to ask your question on the https://discourse.gnome.org/